# Check if Djoser user exists by email

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I am currently working developing a login screen where I am using `djoser` for authentication.

I already use the `/users/` and `/token/login/` endpoints to create and log in users respectively in the frontend (JS `fetch`) and I know that `/users/` will return an error message if the user already exists (which I'm displaying with react-hook-form).

My question is: is there a way of verifying if the user already exists with their email only (without trying to create an account and working it out from the error message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've found, Djoser doesn't provide a way to check if the email exists, so I wrote an APIView

```
class CheckEmail(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        email = request.GET.get('email')
        user = UserAccount.objects.filter(email=email)
        if user:
            return Response('Email exists')
        else:
            return Response('Welcome aboard!')
```

and used a get request with Yup and Formik:

```
const LoginSchema = Yup.object().shape({
checkEmail: Yup.boolean().default(true),
email: Yup.string()
  .email("Please enter valid email")
  .required("Email is required")
  .when("checkEmail", {
    is: true,
    then: Yup.string()
      .test({
        message: () => "Email already exists",
        test: async(email) => {
          if(email) {
            try {
              let response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/accounts/users/check_email/?email=${email}`);
              if (response.data === 'Welcome aboard!') {
                return true;
              } else {
                return false;
              }
            } catch (error) {
              //console.log(error);
            }
          }
        }
      })
  }),
```

Hope that helps